# Error while loading html in webview from Assets folder in android while used multiple activities

Tags: android, android-webview

I have two activities in my android project. Both contents `WebView` and load same html(which include some javascript code also) file from assets folder.

When I load `WebView` in first activity it works fine. But after navigating to second activity, same html file doesn't load in `WebView`.

Activity 1:

```
 public class Activity_1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity__1);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_1.this, Activity_2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sample.html");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Activity 2:

```
    public class Activity_2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview2);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        else
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                progressDialog.setProgress(newProgress);
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sample.html");
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}
```

activity_1.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_2.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

When I open second activity, I get stuck as,

[image]

I don't understand that same html is loading properly in first Activity, but not in the second.

I also tried with clear `WebView` cache in first activity and destroying `WebView` in `onDestroy` of activity 1.

To load html, I tried with following methods:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/sample.html");
```

OR

Access html from storing as string resource

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, getResources().getString(R.string.html), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Edit:

I tried with uninstalling webview updates and its working fine.
Is there any problem with webview updates in android 5.0?

Please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which Exception you got?

Comment: can u specify on which android version you are testing your app?

Comment: Thats the problem ..i am not getting any exception or error. But the page is not loading in second activity.

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia: I am testing on android lollipop 5.0. Nexux 6 Device

Comment: I have tested your code with a test html file which is working fine in second activity too. have you tried running your sample in other devices?

Comment: I just tried with simple HTML, its working around 80% times. But when you add some complex HTML with javascript code. It shows same screen with stuck at 90%.

Comment: I tried on many devices. I found that problem seems to be on Nexus 6 and android 5.0 devices

Answer (score 0):

I've done a similar project to try your code. It's working for me :S

Maybe you can try to place you file in src/main/assets and use this line

webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sample.html");

But in my case is working with two options. ¿Can you provide more info about html file please?

Comment: The html file contains javascript code to run the animation. The animation seems to contain lots of mathematics calculations.

Comment: I was reserching the problem this weekend. It looks like Lollipop 5.0 has a bug with synchronously javascript load in a webview:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79924

But it seems be fixed on 5.1. Can you try in a Nexus with 5.1? Can you try to update webview component on your phone to lastest (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview)

If not, can you provide the html file to test in my code? Does your code work with simple javascript code?